# What is the best way to log all user request operations: (inserts, updates, deletes in Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database with 50 tables and I want to log users requests, such as inserts, updates or deletes on all the tables in the database.  I can also create a trigger for this for each request type.

What is the best way to do this from a  performance perspective or is there a better way to track this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also create audit tables which are populated by triggers (and which allow much more flexibility than change data capture). The critical component is to capture sets of data not try to work row-by-row.  It does add some overhead yes, but if you write the triggers correctly, it isn't that much. Be sure to capture who (including which application if you have multiple applications hitting the database) and when as well as the old and new values. Set up one audit table per table you want audited (too much locking if you use only one audit table). And at the time you set up your system, write the code to get data back from a bad transaction or set of transactions. That makes it easier to recover when you do have something go wrong and you need to revert. We use two tables per table audited, one contains the info about the process that did the changes (name of the application, date, user, etc. and an auditid), the other contains the details about what was changed (old and new values, ID of the record being affected and column affected). Our structure enables us to use the same structure for each table being audited, and allows the tables to change without having to change the audit table and allows us to easily script the audit tables for a new tables. It is also easy for us to see what records were changed at the same time or in the same process or to find out which of the many applications which touch our database was responsible for the bad data as well as telling us who in particular was responsible for the bad data. This helps us track down application bugs and find out why the data was changed the way it was in some cases. It also makes it easier for us to track down all the data that was affected by a broken process rather than just the one we knew about.

Comment: thanks for all replies, and specially for you. i found my response.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Enterprise Edition, look into [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx). If you don't have Enterprise and aren't interested in capturing the historical values of the columns that change, look into [Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462.aspx).

See [Comparing Change Data Capture and Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280519.aspx) to understand the differences between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all requests to insert, update and/or delete data goes through some middle-tier data access layer, I would suggest you do your logging there. This is where we do all of ours. It is much simpler than trying to extract the actual insert / delete / update statements out of SQL Server.

If you want to do auditing of data, you can look into [Change Data Capture (CDC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx). But this requires the Enterprise Edition.

Comment: This is a truly bad idea as it doesn't catch all changes to the database. It especially won't catch changes not made by the application such as employees committing fraud. This is a very poor idea for auditing data.

Comment: @HLGEM - It wasn't clear to me what he's asking. If he simply wants to track all Select, Delete and Update statements, logging in the middle tier is fine. If he wants to do formal auditing data, he should be using CDC. This is why I suggested both.

Comment: No the middle tier is the worst place to do this, as it doesn't catch all inserts or deletes (the ones not done theough official channels, ie the middle tier are the most critical to catch! To do this is the midddle tier is short-sighted.). This must be done at the database level. Having used both auditing tables and CD, I do not recommend CDC as it doesn't give you the flexibilty to get all the information you need and the data expires in only three days unless you move it somewhere else or change the date. Auditing typically needs to stay for the long term not the short term.